# sim number is not getting in android

Tags: android

I used the following code to get to get the sim number and serial number of the sim. But i am getting the sim serial number but not the sim number. I gave the uses permission all the stuffs like that. but i am not getting it.!! Please help me out.!! Thank You.!

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
        String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: What are you getting then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIM number is not compulsory to be there, it's upto the Telecom if they put number inside the SIM card. It's mostly happen they do it for POSTPAID SIM cards, mostly SIMs do not have number so in that case they return null and if it has, it shall return that NUMBER as it is. To make sure your SIM has number or not, do check that in your android mobile settings.

check this link [Check SIM number in android](http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/articles/find-your-sim-card-number-on-android)

Comment: Ok I will check it out that.!!